# Integrating Sharepoint with Quality Center

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, hp-quality-center

I am an intern for a company that wants to try to integrate data from HP Quality Center (graphs, dashboards, data etc) into Sharepoint 2010. The whole idea is that once a test case or something is updated through Quality Center; it should automatically update on sharepoint. Any ideas on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Well quality center does have a database behind it, so you could query that via BCS.

OR, for bonus points since QC doesn't offer any web services, you could expose the data yourself using the COM API that they provide.  We have done this in-house to tie into our own reporting system. non-SharePoint sadly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show QC reports in share point, then you can define the reports in QC, and use OTA (The COM API) to periodically pull those reports and store them in share point.
To find more information regarding the API, just go to help menu, there you can find documentation for both the COM API and for DB structure.

If you want to update data in share point and not show aggregated results, then you can write a workflow script which will be triggered when data is changed in QC. In that script you can do pretty much any thing you want as long as it's COM. So you can go to share point as well and update data there. For workflow documentation and example go to help menu in QC.