# Sharepoint- SSRS Reports-from QC data

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, hp-quality-center

we are using HPQC. now I want to import QC data to Sharepoint so that I can display reports and create charts based on the QC data . Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please describe a bit more detailled what you want to do, what you have tried, what your exact problem is (Getting data out of QC? Getting data into Sharepoint? Both? Anything?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749596/integrating-sharepoint-with-quality-center) you have two possibilities:

- Use BCS (as also stated [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/06a72347-0ef5-4073-bf89-d5ac92e8a568/how-to-integrate-hp-quality-center-with-share-point-2010?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)).
- Use the OTA API or if you have some new QC version, you can also use the REST API to get the data from QC.

Answer (score 0):

The data will need to be in a SQL table on a server that has SSRS component installed.  I am not familiar with  Quality-center but it may just be easier to use a page-viewer web part if it's not standard SQL databasing used.